# Titanium Alloy Set Visible does not always work

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I frequently use the method to set the visibility

```
$.abort.setVisible(true);
```

but I have problems, not all the times it has happened, sometimes it happens that does not work is possibile?
(I call in a `callback` that runs to the success of an http request)

Comment: Please provide more source code presenting your issue.

Comment: the element is probably hidden under another view, but it's hard to say without the code

Comment: If you wait 20ms before setting the visibility, do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem, and strangely we resolved it simply switching from

`.setVisible(true);`  to  `.show();`

and

`.setVisible(false);` to `.hide();`